# sudo trimforce disable not working

Tags: ssd, high-sierra, startup

Not so long ago, my early 2013 MacBookPro used to boot in a sweet 13s.
Since I updated to High Sierra, this has turned into an ugly 58s.

I read here and there that the startup slownesses in high sierra are linked to the TRIM option being on. I tried to turn it off:

> sudo trimforce disable

The instruction seems to work and after a couple of confirmations and warnings the system rebooted, but it didn't show any improvement. When I checked, TRIM was still on.

Then I tried to run the same instruction in single user mode, also unsuccessfully:

> Disabling TRIM...
>
> touch: /System/Library/Extensions/: Read-only file system
>   .
>   Operation failed (error 1).

Can someone help run this instruction?
High Sierra slow startup time seem common to many people, is there another approach to fix them?
Any idea why Apple still hasn't fixed after several updates?

Many thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you can disable TRIM on an default Apple SSD (at least on HS).

Comment: Although I believe it is the case, how can I be sure that I have a default apple SSD? (I bought the mac second hand)

Comment: Go to Apple Menu -> About This Mac ->More Info ->System Report and then Hardware. Thecn check for Serial-ATA and you can find your SSD details. If it's Apple, you will sees something like "APPLE SSD TS256XX".

Comment: Yes, it's an APPLE SSD SD512E. Still puzzled why I cannot turn off TRIM. Can it have to do with KEXT? Not sure what it's about but I've seen it mentioned [in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272612/trimforce-enable-does-not-work)

Comment: My bad. You can't disable TRIM on Apple SSDs. My first comment has a mistype.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's infuriating how apple can kill the performance of their devices with one os update. I'm starting to be really mad at them after having all sort of similar issues with my phone. They're pushing their customers into buying new expensive devices with these shady practices and it's very wrong.